# Is it posible to change vi regex machine?

Tags: javascript, regex, vim

I'm would love to have a JavaScript syntax like regex in vim, so the can be compatible.

Comment: if you want to write perl regex to do some substitution etc. `:h perldo`

Comment: BTW, this question title is not suitable... regex machine usually refers to NFA/DFA. While "syntax"  is all about 'flavor'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a vim plugin for this.

https://github.com/othree/eregex.vim

I'm currently using this. It's quite fine(though not full-featured).

It disabled instant highlight. It does not support lookaround.

But I still recommend eregex because I strongly miss PCRE.(And it does not require Perl :)

Answer (score 1):

Vim 7.4 now comes with two different regular expression engines (`:set re`), but that just switches between the old and a new, NFA-based engine that can be faster. It doesn't change the *syntax* of its dialect, and doing so would break most plugins, customizations, and habits of Vim users, and therefore is unlikely to happen.

Unfortunately, we have to live with those slight differences between `grep`, Perl, Vim, etc. `:help perl-patterns` contrasts Vim's dialect with Perl's.

Tip: Prepending `\v` to the pattern switches to Vim's *very magic* mode, where you don't have to escape so many characters (e.g. `(foo|bar)+` instead of `\(foo\|bar\)\+`).